# Access to shares denied when posting updates on LinkedIn from windows phone app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, linkedin-api

I am trying to post an  update on LinkedIn from my windows phone application. I have successfully received the AccessToken. But, when requesting with the access token, I am getting an error saying

> Access to shares denied.

I have used the following code for posting update:

```
 private void PostToWall()
    {
        //*****for post****//
        var postUrl = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares?oauth2_access_token=" + User.AccessToken;
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(postUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";

        request.BeginGetRequestStream(StatusPostRequested, request);          
    }
```

`user.AccessToken` contains the access token. When I copy & paste the `postUrl` to browser, I can see the following error message in xml:

```
<error>
<status>403</status>
<timestamp>1486381735143</timestamp>
<request-id>65DZUF9IM0</request-id>
<error-code>0</error-code>
<message>Access to shares denied</message>
</error>
```

I have declared scope like this.

```
scope = "r_basicprofile%20w_share"
```

Can someone point out what might be going wrong here?